# Xcode 5 SpriteKit particle emitter not appearing in editor

Tags: ios, xcode, particles, sprite-kit

Potentially really simple question, but...

has any one else found when selecting the .sks file in this case sparkle the effect doesn't appear in the editor. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: have you tried restarting Xcode?

Comment: Yeah. But thanks for the suggestions. Off and on again. ;)

Comment: now and then it happens - if i selected another emitter file it worked ok again. Generally happen to me when my effects limits on # of particles.

Comment: Thank you @Smick that's exactly what it was.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old post, but I had the same problem lately.

I worked around it by moving to the 'version editor' and then back to the 'standard editor' using the editor selector on the upper right corner of the main toolbar.

This would restart the particle emitter simulation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok - I think I figured this one out as a XCode interface quirk.  There is a hidden "show" / "hide" toggle that only appears on mouse-over (see the images below).

The initial view

[image: Initial view - missing the SpriteKit inspector]

When you mouse-over the "emitter node" line you see the "show" option

[image: Where to mouse-over to see the "show" option]

[image: Restored SpriteKit inspector]

Now everything looks normal

[image: what happens when you move your mouse]

Comment: That wasn't the question.

Comment: I thought it would be helpful because the show/hide functionality is non-obvious. I too have noticed that the editor sometimes fails to render SKS files properly but I don't have a fix for that...